# Restrições no campo texto React

Tags: javascript, html, react

É possível que um campo texto receba somente os caracteres abaixo?

```
numeros | espaço | barra (/) | traço (-)
```

O campo tipo *number* não me ajuda nesse caso, seria legal usar o tipo texto nesse caso?

Comment: Sim é possivel. Por essa ordem ou pode ter a ordem trocada? E o que acontece quando se digita algo "errado"? apaga, ou não deixa preencher?

Comment: Acho que o ideal não é nem deixar aparecer, o que espero de resultado algo como 2016 - 2017 ou 2016 / 2017 e suas varianças sem espaço...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um expressão regular que é uma notação para representar padrões em *strings*. Serve para validar entradas de dados ou fazer busca e extração de informações em textos.

Apesar de já existir uma resposta, resolvi inserir esta para explicar o que faz cada item da expressão regular.

Para este caso:

> numeros | espaço | barra (/) | traço (-)

- `\d` - números
- `\s` - espaço
- `/` - barra
- `-`  - hífen / traço
- `^` - negativa

Veja como fica:

```
[^\d\s-/]
```

Neste [link no regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LqmTCH/1) , você vai ver funcionando a expressão.

Agora abaixo, veja como ficaria a codificação:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: "" };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value.replace(/[^\d\s-/]/g, "") });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          id="text"
          name="password"
          placeholder="Entre aqui com os dados"
          autocomplete="off"
          required
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return <NameForm />;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Veja [funcionando aqui](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-joliot-hx5nm).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a propriedade `onChangeText` do `TextInput` para filtrar o que vai ser alterado no seu `state` local.
Usando a função `replace` (`string`) você pode usar uma expressão regular (exemplo: `/([^\d\s/-])/g`) para filtrar o que o usuário está digitando e remover tudo que é:

- Numeros
- Espacos
- Barra ( / )
- Hífen ( - )

Exemplo:

```
constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        text: '2015',
    };

    this.filterText = this.filterText.bind(this);
}

filterText(text) {
    this.setState({
        text: text.replace(/([^\d\s/-])/g, '')
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <TextInput
                style={{
                    height: 40,
                    width: '90%',
                    borderColor: 'gray',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }}
                onChangeText={this.filterText}
                value={this.state.text}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Material de ajuda:

- [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/) - Para testar suas expressões regulares
- [React Native - Text Input](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) - Manual do Text Input

Answer (score 0):

Como já respondido pelos colegas, é possível solucionar o problema de forma "manual" utilizando regex, entretanto, para manter um projeto mais organizado e consistente, recomendo utilizar bibliotecas específicas que possuem adoção relevante por parte da comunidade. Particularmente gosto do [react-input-mask](https://github.com/sanniassin/react-input-mask), mas existem diversas boas bibliotecas, muitas não específicas para React mas de fácil integração.

Um exemplo solucionando seu problema em questão:

```
<InputMask mask="9999 - 9999" />
```